# How to trigger an event in stub? [vue-test-utils]

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I'm trying to test a component event like this:

```
// template: <form @submit.prevent="save"></form>
const save = jest.fn()
const wrapper = mount(MyComponent, {methods: { save }})
wrapper.find('form').trigger('submit.prevent')
expect(save).toBeCalled() // Called successfully
```

Where the event calls a component method. It works very well
But if i use a custom component, the component method isn't called

```
// template: <my-custom-form @submit="save"></my-custom-form>
const save = jest.fn()
const wrapper = mount(MyComponent, {methods: { save }, stubs: ['my-custom-form']})
wrapper.find('my-custom-form-stub').trigger('submit')
expect(save).toBeCalled() // Expected mock function to have been called, but it was not called.
```

How to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `.native` modifier on the `my-custom-form` component to listen for the native DOM event instead of a custom `submit` event. From the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Binding-Native-Events-to-Components) ..

> There may be times when you want to listen directly to a native event
> on the root element of a component. In these cases, you can use the
> `.native` modifier for `v-on`.

So the following should work in your case ..

```
<my-custom-form @submit.native.prevent="save"></my-custom-form>
```

**EDIT:** See @writofmandamus's comment and @JaredMcAteer's answer below for a better solution.

Comment: Actually i'm doing `<form @submit.prevent="$emit('submit')"> ... </form>` but it doesn't work. Now i tested `<my-custom-form @submit.native.prevent="save"></my-custom-form>` and it worked for me.

Edit your answer please

Comment: @Daniel Okay I'll edit my answer. It's strange though as I expected both methods to work :\

Comment: The first method works in the application, only in the unit tests doesn't works

Comment: So we can't test using non-native events? I rather not have to change my code to get a test to work.

Comment: Looks like you're supposed to use it like `wrapper.find('my-custom-form-stub').vm.$emit('submit')`

Comment: @writofmandamus That's indeed a better solution. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 34):

From @writofmandamus, in the comments of the accepted answer, provided a more general use answer, since changing the event binding to `.native` may not be possible or desired.

You can emit an event from a component stub with:

v2:

```js
wrapper.findComponent('my-custom-component-stub').vm.$emit('custom-event');
```

v1:

```js
wrapper.find('my-custom-component-stub').vm.$emit('custom-event');
```

Comment: Yes, this should be the correct answer, since you don't want to change the component itself.

Comment: you'll want to use wrapper.findComponent instead of wrapper.find

Comment: Updated to reflect changes in the API since the time of writing.

Comment: Note for anyone else, if you are stubbing your component, you need to add `-stub` for it to be found. So if your component was `CustomComponent` with html tag `<custom-component>` you would need to have `wrapper.findComponent('custom-component-stub')` for it to be found.